Understanding SmallProxy Contract Behavior with ImplementationA
I'm currently doing some experiments with the SmallProxy contract. Below is the code for the SmallProxy and ImplementationA contracts:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol";

contract SmallProxy is Proxy {
    address public admin; //added this

    bytes32 private constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;

    //added this
    function setSomeAddress(address newAdmin) external {
        admin = newAdmin;
    }

    function setImplementation(address newImplementation) public {
        assembly {
            sstore(_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT, newImplementation)
        }
    }

    function _implementation() internal view override returns (address implementationAddress) {
        assembly {
            implementationAddress := sload(_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT)
        }
    }

    // helper function
    function getDataToTransact(uint256 numberToUpdate) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("setValue(uint256)", numberToUpdate);
    }

    function readStorage() public view returns (uint256 valueAtStorageSlotZero) {
        assembly {
            valueAtStorageSlotZero := sload(0)
        }
    }
}

contract ImplementationA {
    address public owner;

    function setOwner() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

Here is the unit test I wrote for these contracts:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {ImplementationA, SmallProxy} from "../../src/24-PuzzleWallet/ProxyExample/SmallProxy.sol";

contract SmallProxyTest is Test {
    ImplementationA implementationA;
    SmallProxy smallProxy;

    address owner = makeAddr("owner");
    address attacker = makeAddr("attacker");

    function setUp() public {
        vm.startPrank(owner, owner);

        // init impl contract
        implementationA = new ImplementationA();

        // setup proxy
        smallProxy = new SmallProxy();
        smallProxy.setImplementation(address(implementationA));
        implementationA = ImplementationA(address(smallProxy));
        
        vm.stopPrank();
    
        assertEq(address(0), smallProxy.admin()); // passed
        assertEq(address(0), implementationA.owner()); // passed
    }

    function testStorageLayout() public {
        // part 1 owner to attacker
        vm.startPrank(attacker, attacker);
        smallProxy.setSomeAddress(attacker);
        vm.stopPrank();

        assertEq(attacker, smallProxy.admin()); // passed
        assertEq(attacker, implementationA.owner()); // passed

        // part 2 attacker to owner
        vm.startPrank(owner, owner);
        implementationA.setOwner();
        vm.stopPrank();

        assertEq(owner, smallProxy.admin()); // passed
        assertEq(owner, implementationA.owner()); // passed
    }
}

First, I'm assuming that ImplementationA and SmallProxyContract are two independent contracts, each one with its own storage layout. I'm puzzled by the behavior of:
Changing the Admin Address

SmallProxy::setSomeAddress is supposed to set a new address for the admin variable in slot 0 of SmallProxy.
However, implementationA.owner is also changed to the attacker’s address, despite no delegatecall being present in SmallProxy::setSomeAddress.
I expected only SmallProxy.admin to change, but both are being updated. Why is this happening?

Changing the Owner Address

When calling implementationA.setOwner(), both admin and owner are updated to the owner's address.
Again, there’s no delegatecall in this function, so why are both variables being updated?

Now this contract utilizes Proxy from OpenZeppelin, so my guess is that something is happening behind the scenes with the fallback and delegatecall function that I'm not able to understand.

Can someone provide a mental model to understand this behavior? What is really happening step by step?
Are there any resources or documentation that could help clarify this?

Thank you in advance!

implementationA in your code is set to the same address of smallProxy in this line:
implementationA = ImplementationA(address(smallProxy));

So by calling implementationA.owner() you're calling the proxy and reading from it. This explains why it returns the attacker.
Similarly, doing implementationA.setOwner(); will write to the proxy, changing the admin.
Removing that line should solve your problem.
